# Build URL with HTML CR in string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with VBA interpreting a string variable instead of leaving the contents as a literal value. I am using VBA to build a URL with a varied internal structure.

The URL structure is basically:

```
http://*internalsiteaddress.com*/list?utf8=*Variable1*%0D%0AVariable2%0D%0A*=Search*
```

The URL is a list between 1 and 30 variables. To build it I am running a simple loop that takes the the additional Variable and adds %0D%0A and the next list variable until the whole list is added so that

```
URL=URL & "%0D%0A" & Variable2
```

It essentially is working as it should except that it is ignoring the %0D%0A portion. So instead of getting the above expected result I get the variables all together without the %0D%0A separator.

I am assuming that the VBA is interpreting the %0D%0A as a new line/Carriage Return (Which technically it is of course) and not maintaining its literal value. So I end up with -

```
http://*internalsiteaddress.com*/list?utf8=*Variable1Variable2*=Search*
```

Comment: VBA has no idea about percent encoding and does not have any string escaping (beyond quotes) so the problem is elsewhere - either how you submit the request or how its processed by the server.

Comment: I just verified what you said using msgbox to display the completed URL and the %0D%0A IS in the structure. So now I am more lost.

The steps after are to activate the web browser, Send Keys F6, Sendkeys URL

I changed the appactivate to go to Notepad and verified the loss is in SendKeys. I have never had that issue with Sendkeys before

Comment: Well % is something significant to SendKeys (alt or control or the like) try escaping them "{%}0D{%}0A"

Comment: There are better ways to just submit data to a url btw.

Comment: I know that there are better ways. I am forced into it by a few other outside issues. Using {} worked. Thanks